# Using JNAerator to access a library under Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, jna, jnaerator

If I run JNAerator using the header for my library, the process gobbles processor time and never seems to finish - after first issuing warnings:

```
adrian$ java -Xmx128m -jar ~/JNAerator/jnaerator/target/jnaerator-0.13-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar /Users/adrian/DRAMSim2/DRAMSim.h -mode StandaloneJar
Warning: no -library option for file 'DRAMSim.h', using "DRAMSim".
Auto-configuring parser...
Parsing native headers...

/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:74:25: warning: #warning "Unsupported compiler detected"
/usr/include/_types/_wctype_t.h:30:19: warning: No newline before end of file
```

So, I have also tried the -ScanSymbols option:

```
java -Xmx128m -jar ~/JNAerator/jnaerator/target/jnaerator-0.13-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar -scanSymbols  -mode StandaloneJar
Auto-configuring parser...
Parsing native headers...
Normalizing parsed code...
Generating libraries...


Compiling JNAerated files...


[....]


Copying runtime classes...
Generating out.jar
#
# SUCCESS: JNAeration completed !
# Output mode is 'StandaloneJar(JAR with bindings and runtime dependencies)
#
# => '/Users/adrian/groovy/simul/src/simul/./out.jar'
```

And out.jar has a great many .class files but no .java and I have no idea how to use it.

Using -noComp -noJar as suggested in the wiki generates no output at all ...

```
adrian$ java -Xmx128m -jar ~/JNAerator/jnaerator/target/jnaerator-0.13-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar -scanSymbols  -noComp -noJar
WARNING: option (?i)-noComp is deprecated and might be removed in future versions.
WARNING: option (?i)-noJar is deprecated and might be removed in future versions.
WARNING: legacy options (?i)-noJar and (?i)-noComp used, defaulting -mode to Directory
Auto-configuring parser...
Parsing native headers...
Normalizing parsed code...
Generating libraries...

#
# SUCCESS: JNAeration completed !
# Output mode is 'Directory(Bindings sources in simple file hierarchy)
#
# => '/Users/adrian/groovy/simul/src/simul/.'
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a hopeless case?

Comment: Do you have a link to the header file you are trying to convert?

Comment: It's on github - see http://www.eng.umd.edu/~blj/dramsim/#htoc6 and https://github.com/dramninjasUMD/DRAMSim2/blob/master/DRAMSim.h

Comment: OK, found that one on google, typed exactly what you typed, and had no problems.  So the error messages are definitely relevant...  using latest Java, etc.?

Comment: Can you try your first command using the `-verbose:class` switch?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WvHyu1Mz

Comment: When I run it I only get the first two include statements, I do not get the c++ includes.

Comment: With -verbose:class it crashes ... http://pastebin.com/8w4pdmY1

Comment: Yeah, sorry about confusion... the -v switch I said the first time is for JNAerator and -verbose:class is for java (need to put it earlier on commandline for it to work)

Comment: This looks like identical symptoms to you... https://github.com/nativelibs4java/nativelibs4java/issues/564

Comment: I suspect your issue is in the c++ includes.  Is 4.2 the latest version?  Can you upgrade your C compiler?  Can you temporarily rename/suppress the `c++` directory so JNAerator doesn't find it and defaults to gcc?

Comment: Paste of output with verbose:class http://pastebin.com/MF44YLtf

Comment: Thanks.   A few more questions.  1. What c compiler are you using?  `gcc --version`   2.  What is the contents of `_jnaerator.preprocessed.c` ?